# VBA Function always return TRUE

Tags: excel, vba, function, outlook

I had this function that loops through my *Outlook Inbox* and return `Boolean` as end result if there's an email that meet my set condition. 
The function always returns true even if the condition is wrong. I replace `.Sender` to `xxxxxxx` and it also returns `True`.

The `GetSMTPAddressForRecipients` was from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/obtain-the-e-mail-address-of-a-recipient) Only changes `Sub` to `Function GetSMTPAddressForRecipients(mail As Outlook.MailItem)`

What had I done wrong?

```
Function CheckInbox(ByVal fpemail As Variant) As Boolean

CheckInbox = False

Dim objOutlook As Object, objNamespace As Object, objFolder As Object
Dim EmailCount As Integer
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

On Error Resume Next
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim tdyDate As Date
Dim checkDate As Date
tdyDate = Format(Now(), "Short Date")
checkDate = DateAdd("d", -7, tdyDate) ' DateAdd(interval,number,date)

 Dim iCount As Integer, DateCount As Integer
 EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
 DateCount = 0

 ' loop the mailbox
 For iCount = 1 To EmailCount
 'check for sender.email type first, mine is 'EX'
 With objFolder.Items(iCount)
    If DateSerial(Year(.ReceivedTime), Month(.ReceivedTime), Day(.ReceivedTime)) >= checkDate And _
       DateSerial(Year(.ReceivedTime), Month(.ReceivedTime), Day(.ReceivedTime)) <= tdyDate And _
       .Subject Like "Test Subject" And _
       .Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress = "xxxxxxx" And _
       GetSMTPAddressForRecipients(.To) = fpemail Then
       CheckInbox = True
       Exit Function
    Else
       CheckInbox = False
    End If
 End With
 Next iCount

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objNamespace = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Temporarily remove the `On Error Resume Next` and tell us what errors you get on the `If` statement.  (If the `If` has an error, the next statement is `CheckInbox = True`.)  You might even have errors earlier than the `If`, but you are letting it continue to run until it hits the `If` and then gets an error there too - possibly because an object is not set or something similar.  But we can't easily tell what until you remove the error masking.

Comment: @YowE3K Run-time Error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set, highlights my whole IF condition...

Comment: My **guess** is it is the `objFolder.Items(iCount).Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress` that is failing.  Put some extra statements immediately before the `If` saying `Dim xxxx As Object`, then `Set xxxx = .Sender`, then `Set xxxx = xxxx.GetExchangeUser`, then `Debug.Print xxxx.PrimarySmtpAddress`.  Then run the code and see which of those it crashes on.  (I don't know enough Outlook VBA to know which of those objects won't be valid, so this will be an easy way to test.)

Comment: The `Debug.Print xxxx.PrimarySmtpAddress ` crashes.

Comment: That makes me think that the sender of that email is not a Microsoft Exchange mailbox user (or, at least, not on your company's Exchange) and therefore `objFolder.Items(iCount).Sender.GetExchangeUser` has returned `Nothing`.

Comment: @YowE3K If that's the case for `.Sender`, I can make it to a fixed string but I believed my `GetSMTPAddressForRecipients(.To) = fpemail` also causing the problem... once remove `.Sender`. Error changes to ` Object Required`

Comment: I will search around first and see what I can do.

Comment: I just searched for what you might be using as the `GetSMTPAddressForRecipients` function.  The code I found takes a `MailItem` as the parameter.  Have you modified it to take a string?  If not, that will cause an object required error.  (You may need to use `GetSMTPAddressForRecipients(objFolder.Items(iCount)) = fpemail Then` but, without seeing your code, I can't be sure.)

Comment: You might need to add a `Exit Function` statement after the `CheckInbox = True` so the process ends there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the things you might want to consider:

1. Do early binding first to make sure you are correctly accessing the properties.
    How do you do that? Just add reference to *Outlook Library* under *Tools>References*.

   > Microsoft Outlook XX.0 Object Library
2. Now, make sure that you are working with an *Outlook MailItem Object*. You can try inserting a check within your loop. Something along the lines:

   ```
   Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem '/* add declaration to make use of intellisense */

   '/* backward loop, but starts with most recent email */
   For iCount = EmailCount To 1 Step -1 
       ' check for sender.email type first, mine is 'EX'
       If TypeOf objFolder.Items(iCount) Is MailItem Then
           Set objItem = objFolder.Items(iCount)
           With objItem
               '...rest of code here

           End With
       End if
   Next
   ```

   I don't know but you put a comment to check the type first but never seen a code to do it so I put a check on the type of item.
3. You don't need to use `DateSerial` and all the other function to compare dates. You can simply:

   ```
   If Format(.ReceivedTime, "Short Date") >= checkdate Then
   ```
4. I don't know if you are testing the `Subject` with a string `Test Subject` in it or equal to it. For the first, I think it should be:

   ```
   And .Subject Like "*Test Subject*"
   ```

   Above returns all subject with a *Test Subject* in it. Or better yet:

   ```
   And Instr(.Subject, "Test Subject") <> 0
   ```

   If however you are trying to get `MailItem` with `Subject` equal to *Test Subject* then just use:

   ```
   And .Subject = "Test Subject"
   ```
5. Make sure that you are actually retrieving something out of this (which should be an email address).

   ```
   .Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
   ```
6. The `GetSMTPAddressForRecipients` procedure expects a `MailItem` but you provided the `MailItem` *To property* (you said you used it as is and just converts it to a function). Take note also that procedure will get all the recipients in the `MailItem` being tested. Why do you need the *SMTP Address* in the first place? I suggest you just use the name? Something along the lines:

   ```
   And Instr(.To, "John Doe") <> 0
   ```

   where *John Doe* is the recipients assigned name.

---

Refactoring your function:

```
Function CheckInbox(ByVal fpemail As String) As Boolean

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application 'As Object
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace 'As Object
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder 'As Object
    '/* added declarations */
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim EmailCount As Integer

    '/* I assumed Outlook is already running, revert to your code other wise */    
    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim tdyDate As Date
    Dim checkDate As Date
    tdyDate = Format(Now(), "Short Date")
    checkDate = DateAdd("d", -7, tdyDate)

    Dim iCount As Integer, DateCount As Integer
    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
    DateCount = 0

    '/* loop the mailbox, same as your code */
    For iCount = EmailCount To 1 Step -1
        '/* Check for the type */
        If TypeOf objFolder.Items(iCount) Is MailItem Then
            '/* Set the object, get intellisense */
            Set objItem = objFolder.Items(iCount)
            With objItem
               If Format(.ReceivedTime, "Short Date") >= checkDate _
               And Format(.ReceivedTime, "Short Date") <= tdyDate _
               And InStr(.Subject, "Test Subject") <> 0 _
               And .Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress = "xxxxxxx" _
               And EvaluateRecipientSMTP(.Recipients, fpemail) Then
               '/* we use below function here */ 
                  CheckInbox = True
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  CheckInbox = False
               End If
            End With
        End If
    Next iCount

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objNamespace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Function
```

---

**Edit1:** The extra function

```
Private Function EvaluateRecipientSMTP(objAllRecip As Outlook.Recipients, _
                                       fpemail As String) As Boolean

    Dim objRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim objExDisUser As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList

    For Each objRecip In objAllRecip
        Select Case objRecip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
        '/* OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry or
        'OlAddressEntryUserType.olOutlookContactAddressEntry */
        Case 0, 10
            Set objExUser = objRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
            If Not objExUser Is Nothing Then
                If objExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress = fpemail Then
                    EvaluateRecipientSMTP = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        '/* OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry */
        Case 1
            Set objExDisUser = objRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
            If Not objExDisUser Is Nothing Then
                If objExDisUser.PrimarySmtpAddress = fpemail Then
                    EvaluateRecipientSMTP = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        '/* recipient not part of your exchange server */
        Case Else
        '/* Do nothing */
        End Select
    Next
End Function
```

**Important:**

1. `fpemail` above is of type `String` which is the recipient name you are looking for.
2. For Item number 5 above, you might want to consider [YowE3K's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202657/2685412) advise.
3. Do not forget to set reference.

Comment: Thanks for the SUPER clear explanation! Just to clarify: Point 4, I 'm trying to get the full subject and Point 5, I received the full name and email address. Point 6, I used email because the email value was from the Cell's value.

Comment: @Max First, don't go changing the accepted answer in an instant. It may or may not be the one you're looking for. Btw, on point 4 and 5, I think that is sorted out (you can use the codes as is). For point 6 though, we might need to tweak it a little by using another function. But this will only work on recipients on your mail server and not those from outside.

Comment: @Max Posted the extra function which checks if any of the recipient is equal to your email address from a cell's value. See if this works for you. If not, God help us lol :)

Comment: Re things to consider point 3 - You don't need even the `Format` - both `.ReceivedTime` and `checkDate` are dates, so you can just compare the two.  (I was actually expecting the `Format` to cause issues due to then comparing a `String` with a `Date`, thinking VBA would convert the `Date` to a `String` and give problems with `"01/05/2018" >= "12/30/2017"` which would be `False`, but VBA is actually converting the `String` to a `Date` and thus doing a `CDate(Format(.ReceivedTime, "Short Date")) >= checkDate`.)

Comment: @L42 Yes, It looks great for now. The email is case sensitive right? I did a testing for `aaa@mail.com` and `AAA@mail.com`. `AAA@mail.com` returns  `True` and `aaa@mail.com` returns `false`

Comment: @Max You can change it to a non case sensitive test by using: `If StrComp(objExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress, fpemail, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then` or classic approach: `If LCase(objExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress) = LCase(fpemail) Then`. Both will be a non-case sensitive comparison.

Comment: @L42 Hi, today I ran the macro several times and realize that `EvaluateRecipientSMTP` function took along time to run > 5mins. Is there anyway I can speed it up?

Comment: @Max Not a chance especially if you have a lot of recipients. Already designed it to exit once match is found. You would have to loop either ways.